# remote server returned 400 bad request for apache2 in ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, docker

I am doing a file upload to my server in WPF. I am not showing this code because it worked for my localhost, so it seems like my server config is bad.
My request arrives in this php script:

**upload.php:**

```
$target_dir = "/var/www/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $reg_id ."&".$to ."&". basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, the file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error    
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file to dir: $target_file.";
        }
    }
} else { 
    throw new UploadException($_FILES['file']['error']); 
} 

class UploadException extends Exception 
{ 
    public function __construct($code) { 
        $message = $this->codeToMessage($code); 
        parent::__construct($message, $code); 
    } 

    private function codeToMessage($code) 
    { 
        switch ($code) { 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 
                $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 
                $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form";
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: 
                $message = "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: 
                $message = "No file was uploaded"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: 
                $message = "Missing a temporary folder"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: 
                $message = "Failed to write file to disk"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: 
                $message = "File upload stopped by extension"; 
                break; 

            default: 
                $message = "Unknown upload error"; 
                break; 
        } 
        echo $message;
        return $message; 
    } 
}     
?>
```

It is working, when my file is smaller then 2KB, very strange... Everything which is bigger, was declined immediately with error response:

```
Error code: BadRequest
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.99.1 Port 8080</address>
</body></html>
The uploaded file was only partially uploaded
```

So where my error could be? Why is my request invalid when the file is bigger then 2 KB on remote server, but not localhost? I am using Apache2/PHP5 in Docker with Ubuntu 14.04, my php.ini:

post_max_size= 1024M;
upload_max_filesize = 1024M;
memory_limit = 512M;

Comment: `The problem was with the firewall on the system that the system admins had forgotten about completely (sigh). Apparently, the firewall had a file size limit of 2KB imposed`. ???

Comment: Are you try set post_max_size with lower value something like 64M?

Comment: I am testing it locally right now (with docker reference) and disabled my firewall for a few minutes, no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also try to set memory limit in php higher? In php.ini

```
 memory_limit = 32M
```

Comment: I added it, it also was increased.